# COPY package.json - Dockerfile

Tags: json, node.js, docker, dockerfile

I did a Dockerfile to a project in Node.js but an error happened.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN npm install nodemon -g
WORKDIR ./app
COPY package.json ./app
RUN npm install -g
COPY server.js ./app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When I tried building this Dockerfile happen an error like this:

```
Step 4/8 : COPY package.json ./app
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderXXXXXXXX/package.json: no such file or directory
```

How can I fix it?

Docker version 17.12.0

Comment: What is your project structure?

Comment: This means there is no `package.json` in your context folder which you have used with `docker build`. You use `docker build <foldername>` then that folder should have a `package.json` in the root folder itself

Comment: check your docker ignore and and remove ./app make it just /app

Comment: can share your project structure  with docker file

Comment: Tarun Lalwani I had put the package.json in other folder, I did your suggested and worked the Dockerfile

Comment: Yuankun and Adiii it's my structure https://github.com/wrj95/NodeDock I posted in my Git, i learning docker yet, but tks for the help

Comment: I have the same issue and this is my folder structure. https://github.com/JayaniSumudini/OpenLibrary  In this I have package.json, server.js, Dockerfile in same folder level.then what's the wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Do not ever run **nodemon** in production (if that's what you tried to do).
You should configure your **restart** in case if app crashes. Preferably, set it to `always` in docker-compose.yml

The best way to structure Dockerfile  in your case:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR ./app
# please note, you already declared a WORKDIR, 
# therefore your files will be automaticaly pushed to ./app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install -g
COPY ./ ./ 
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Hope, that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have package.json and server.js files in the same directory of your Dockerfile and it should work.

When you build a docker image, the whole content of the directory becomes your docker build context, and docker will find the files you COPY or ADD from there.

You might sometime wants to prevent some of those files to be sent to the build context, in which case you use the .dockerignore file to specify those files. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, move all files to the `WORKDIR` than execute your `npm install`

```
FROM node:latest
RUN npm install nodemon -g
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: I made this, but, i dont know the reason, but don't find the package.json in workdir, then I followed the suggested of put the package.json in root folder of the my project and worked correctly. Tks for the help man

Comment: oh yeah, the package.json should be in the root folder of the project. You're welcome